# How can I access a HTML attribute from this Javascript/jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following

```
<div id="entries_list">
    <div id="entry_51" class="entry" data-entry_id="51">
        some text
    </div>
</div>
```

I am making `entries_list` [sortable using jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). I need to do something when the user 'drops' an entry div, which can be done by:

```
$("#entries_list").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
    }
});
```

What is the easiest way to access the `data-entry_id` attribute of the entry div from within the `stop` function? The console ouput of `ui` looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
alert(ui.item.attr("data-entry_id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`ui.item` is provided as a jquery object, so you can directly do `ui.item.data('data_entry')`

```
$("#entries_list").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log( ui.item.data('entry_id') );
    }
});
```

will put `51` to the console *in this example*.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jKPty/

Answer (score 0):

Use the .data() function - http://api.jquery.com/data/.  Note that HTML5 "data-" attributes are specified without the leading "data-" (hence, just "entry_id").

```
ui.item.data("entry_id")
```